# SQL Replacing HREF of HTML Structure if href contains substring

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, there is this column called blog_content that has html structures of blog posts. In those html structures, there are 2 types of links with the following structure:

- `<a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/how-to-do-smth">Link Title</a>`
- `<a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/learn-to-do#h_4980b42263" target="_self">Link Title 2</a>`

Note --- these anchor tags aren't the only HTML that's on 1 row. 1 Row could have multiple anchor tags. Like this:

```
<h3 data-post-processed="true" id="h_e1f9f37659">Overview</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/how-to-do-smth">Link Title</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/learn-to-do#h_4980b42263" target="_self">Link Title 2</a></p>
    </li>
            <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/learn-to-do#h_4991b33215" target="_self">Link Title 3</a></p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I am trying to replace the href attribute of all  tags that include "#h_" in their own href.

For example, the row above should look like this:

```
<h3 data-post-processed="true" id="h_e1f9f37659">Overview</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="https://service-domain/en/articles/how-to-do-smth">Link Title</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="#h_4980b42263" target="_self">Link Title 2</a></p>
    </li>
            <li>
        <p class="no-margin"><a class="service-content-link" href="#h_4991b33215" target="_self">Link Title 3</a></p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I'm not sure how to approach this because I've found 2-3 threads relatively similar to mine.

Is this something that's even achievable in SQL?

Comment: I am not clear what you have on the database and what you want to change from what into what. Can you try again, good examples are always useful

Comment: I've edited the post. Maybe it is a bit more specific now

Comment: So there is a cell on a table that has One `<a....` or there are multiple `<a...` tags in the one table cell. Maybe if you showed us this one cell in the table where this has occured and then we can be sure what we have to start with

Comment: But it looks like the snippet of code I've added in my post. Not sure how else I can share the cells with you, given that 1 cell could contain 70-80 lines of HTML on average.

Comment: Ok, so that answers some of the question, thanks. So what are you going to want to change these bit To?

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong, but each cell/row under the column blog_content contains HTML and inside that HTML there can be <a> tags that look like the snippet of code from my post. I am trying to replace the HREF attributes that contain '#h_' with '#h_' and everything that follows this separator. So instead of having hrefs like "https://service-domain/en/articles/learn-to-do#h_4980b42263" I want to replace it to "#h_4980b42263".

Comment: I would not do this in SQL. I would use some other language to read the data from the database; parse the HTML with a proper SQL parser and not with regular expressions; make the appropriate changes to the HTML; and then update the SQL in the database. Trying to do this in SQL is going to be error-prone and painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(blog_content, 'href="[^#"]+#h_(.+)"', 'href="#h_$1"') from blog_posts
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a850150fd7ebb2a19058ae63a984af6).

Comment: I've tried using your SQL snippet after I've replaced my dummy variables, but it seems it stops after the first iteration. So for example, it replaces the first href, but it doesnt replace the others. Any ideas of why that might be? 
Here's my fiddle without the dummy variables: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3ba685f3755bc3f24abad53eaa936a8

Comment: @tearswep The issue is that the `a` element `class` names in your latest fiddle are different from the ones in the OP (`service-content-link` to `intercom-content-link`). I updated the regex to be service agnostic https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a850150fd7ebb2a19058ae63a984af6